# Dynamic type of view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some repetitive code I'm trying to refactor:

```
if (_currentIndex >= [_questions count] - 1) {
    [patient setDate:[NSDate date]];
    ConfirmationViewController *confirmation = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Confirmation"];
    [confirmation setPatient:patient];
    [confirmation setQuestions: _questions];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:confirmation animated:YES];

} else if ([[_questions objectAtIndex:_currentIndex + 1] isEqualToString:@"date"]) {
    DateViewController *dateView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Date"];
    [dateView setPatient:patient];
    [dateView setQuestions: _questions];
    [dateView setCurrentIndex: _currentIndex + 1];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dateView animated:YES];
} else {
    QuestionViewController *nextQuestion = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Question"];
    [nextQuestion setCurrentIndex:_currentIndex + 1];
    [nextQuestion setPatient:patient];
    [nextQuestion setQuestions: _questions];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextQuestion animated:YES];
}
```

I'd like to declare a variable `nextView` that can either be a ConfirmationViewController, DateViewController, or QuestionViewController, since all of these have the steps `setPatient:patient`, `[self.navigationController pushViewController...]` and `[setQuestions:_questions]`, and just call that block after the case-specific pieces of code are run, but since they are all different types I can't figure out how I would declare this 'view' variable (I have mostly JS background so I'm used to `var`-ing at the top!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your three view controllers implement a common protocol:

```
@protocol BaseViewController
    @property (readwrite, copy) MyPatient *patient;
    @property (readwrite, copy) NSArray *questions;
@end;

@interface ConfirmationViewController : UITableViewController <BaseViewController>
...
@end
@interface DateViewController : UIViewController <BaseViewController>
...
@end
@interface QuestionViewController : UIViewController <BaseViewController>
...
@end
```

Now you can make a variable of type `BaseViewController`, and set the common properties outside of the conditional:

```
UIViewController<BaseViewController> *vc;
if (_currentIndex >= [_questions count] - 1) {
    [patient setDate:[NSDate date]];
    vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Confirmation"];
} else if ([[_questions objectAtIndex:_currentIndex + 1] isEqualToString:@"date"]) {
    vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Date"];
    [vc setCurrentIndex: _currentIndex + 1];
} else {
    vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Question"];
    [vc setCurrentIndex:_currentIndex + 1];
}
[vc setPatient:patient];
[vc setQuestions: _questions];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: One of them (ConfirmationViewController) is a tableViewController - is it possible to make that one share the base class?

Comment: @thisAnneM You can use a common protocol, take a look at the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee they all have a `patient` and they all have `questions` then you could either make them all inherit from a single UIViewController subclass that has those things or make them all adopt a protocol that requires those things. Personally, I'd go for the UIViewController subclass.